# C# Join two List<int>, remove duplicates, NO LINQ

Tags: c#, list, join, int

This is the idea: I have two `List<int>` and I want to make a third `List<int>` with the above mentioned lists joined, without duplicates. I know how to use `.Union` but I want to make this without using LINQ. So far I have this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers for first list: ");
List<int> firstList = new List<int>{20, 40, 10, 10, 30, 80};
//Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers for second list: ");
List<int> secondList = new List<int> {25, 20, 40, 30, 10 };
//Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
List<int> newList = new List<int>();
foreach (var item in firstList)
{
    if (secondList.Contains(item))
    {
        continue;
    }
}
newList.Sort();
newList.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p));
```

And I am actually stuck...I think that I need to iterate each one of the lists and if the items are equal, add them just once to the new list...But I can't seem to figure out how to do that if the lists are different count.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why no linq? Why deprive yourself of using the right tool? That's like asking...how do I get this nail to hold these boards together *NO HAMMERS*.

Comment: @CaffGeek `Gorilla Glue I hear works wonders..LOL` good analogy

Comment: This is why we have buggy software, with way too many lines of code in them. Because people don't use well tested, and proven libraries.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is using a old (pre LINQ) version of C#?

Comment: Using the LINQ methods is the right thing to do. The right way to do it without them is to **implement them**. There was a time when those methods did not exist; someone had to write them. You can too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is presented with a big (and I do mean **big**) caveat - it's going to be slow. You *will* get much better performance from using LINQ or a different collection (eg. HashSet). This approach is O(n^2) whereas LINQ etc. is O(n).

Simply loop over the second list adding the value to the first if it's not already in the list.

```
foreach (var item in secondList)
{
    if (!firstList.Contains(item))
    {
        firstList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Given that you want a new list at the end of the process you can just add all the items from the first list to the result before the above code:

```
foreach (var item in firstList)
{
    newList.Add(item);
}
```

and replace `firstList` with `newList` when adding.

Comment: OMG thank you so much... I was watching this for so much time and as I said, I glitched. :D

Comment: Please don't follow this suggestion. O(n^2) with suggested approach vs. O(n) with default LINQ. Not bad gain of *slowness* :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - oh indeed. Very slow, but meets the OP's request.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I know that! This is just a simple logic exercise :)

Comment: @ChrisF - You don't need LINQ to get O(n). Just use the right type of collection.

Answer (score -1):

You could take advantage of different types of collections to do the following:

```
var set = new HashSet<int>(firstList);
set.UnionWith(secondList);

var newList = new List<int>(set);
```

Comment: The OP explicitly states he doesn't want to use LINQ.

Comment: @ChrisF - My mistake. Been too long since I used .NET (and had to read the docs). Updated.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
newList.AddRange(firstList);
newList.AddRange(secondList);
newList = newList.Distinct().ToList();
newList.Sort();
```

Comment: While it may answer similar question it can't be answer to this one - if you notice "NO LINQ" is barly mentioned in title.