# How to improve algorithm of IndexOfAll?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

For the sake of learning data structures and algorithms, I am trying to create a simple class with a method named `IndexOfAll`. The method would find all indexes that match any of the given items.

I am trying to find a better algorithm that the one I did. This is what I have written using C#:

```
public class CustomCollection<T> where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    private T[] _items;

    public CustomCollection(T[] items)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(items, nameof(items));
        _items = items;
    }

    public int[] IndexOfAll(T[] items)
    {
        var list = new List<int>();

        for (var i = 0; i < _items.Length; i++)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if (!_items[i].Equals(item))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                list.Add(i);
            }
        }

        return list.ToArray();
    }
}
```

This algorithm uses nested loops which will be very expensive when both `_items` and `items` are large.

How can I write the same function using a better algorithm that would have a better performance?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do a [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins).

Comment: @gunr2171 yes that is what I am trying to do. I want to do it without using Linq. I am trying to figure out the best way to do it using a low level approach.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212567/c-sharp-join-two-listint-remove-duplicates-no-linq#comment58140468_35212567

Comment: @gunr2171 as per the OP, I am trying to learn data-structures and algorithms. So I want to use a lower level approach to get understanding of performance and costs. Using Linq does not really help me understand how the operation is done behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dictionary<T, int>` to improve the performance.

```cs
public class CustomCollection<T> where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    private T[] _items;
    private Dictionary<T, int> _indexes;

    public CustomCollection(T[] items)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(items, nameof(items));

        _items = items;
        _indexes = new Dictionary<T, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            _indexes.Add(items[i], i);
    }

    public int[] IndexOfAll(T[] items)
    {
        return items.Select(item => _indexes[item])
                    .ToArray();

    }
}
```

Please notice that this code will not work, if the source array has identical elements.

Comment: IMO, `T` should also be `notnull`, and both `_items` and `_indexes` should be `readonly`. Also, consider using `IReadOnly<>` interfaces instead of mutable collections for field-types to avoid possible inadvertent mutation?

Comment: `this code will not work, if the source array has identical elements` will list just the last index for non-unique values.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `HashSet` for `items` to *get rid* of inmost `foreach (var item in items)` loop, i.e.

```
// Let's generalize the solution
public int[] IndexOfAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, 
                           IEqualityComparer<T>? comparer = default) {
  ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(items);

  var hashSet = items.ToHashSet(comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
  List<int> result = new();

  for (var i = 0; i < _items.Length; i++)
    if (hashSet.Contains(_items[i]))
      result.Add(i);

  return result.ToArray();
}
```